# can't change the payload text in the Get Started button

Tags: postback, facebook-messenger, payload, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to change the payload text "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD" in the Get Started button in my Facebook Messenger chatbot. For example like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"start"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Like the example at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button but with another payload text.

But the returned value of the payload is still "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"!! I can change other payload texts in other messenges but not in this Get Started button. I wonder if anyone here might know how to change this payload text??

Comment: any luck with this?
i have trying the same, i am unable to edit the welcome text.
Also, i am unable to add the GetStarted button after once i deleted it.
the reponse is success always but nothing changing on chatbot!!

Answer (score 0):

The request has changed for setting GET_STARTED payload .

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<access_token>
{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"FB_GET_STARTED"
  }
}
```

Here is the documentation :
[Facebook GET_STARTED documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button)